# Is the compile time affect the app when deploying it?

Tags: performance, jvm

I'm curious to understand a phrase such as "At compile time however, x language is measurably slower than y language*". Does this mean compile time difference will make one language faster than the other at run-time or in other words when users use the app!

- Both languages work on JVM.

Comment: When you have a question about a phrase, you should provide a link to the source.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to be 100% sure without more info/context, but I'd say "No. Slow compile time doesn't mean slow run time."

Consider two compilers for the same language. One compiles very slowly because it produces heavily optimized code that actually runs faster than the code produced by the other (faster) compiler.